# How do functions pass parameters in D3 and JS calls

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to learn D3.js and JavaScript, etc stuff :)
So here is the code I am seeing in the book:

```
<script>
    function draw(data){
      d3.select("body")
              .append("div")
              .attr("class", "chart")
              .selectAll(".bar")
              .data(data.cash)
              .enter()
              .append("div")
              .attr("class", "bar")
              .style("width", function(d){return d.count/100 +"px"})
              .style("outline", "1px solid blue")
              .text(function(d){return Math.round(d.count)});
    }
</script>
```

I am used to strongly typed languages like .NET or Java so this looks weird to me,
in the line that is saying

```
.style("width", function(d){return d.count/100 +"px"})
```

Where is it getting the values for **"d"** from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous function is passed **but not called** in this piece of code. The `d` parameter is passed to that function by whoever ultimately calls the function – in this case, the d3 library will.

Here's a simpler example, analogous to the code snippet in your question:

```
doSomething(function (someParameter) {
    alert(someParameter);
});
```

And this is the analogous function definition inside of the library:

```
function doSomething(someCallback) {
    var foo = 42;
    someCallback(foo);
}
```